# Why will this program not move the player room to room?

Tags: python

```
    def show_instructions():
      if __name__ == "__main__":
        while True:
          print('Dragon Text Game\n')


print('\t\t\tDragon Text Game.')
print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
------')
print('Move commands: South, North, East, West')
print('Type "Exit" to end the game.')
print("Let's start with your name:  ")

name = input()
print(f'Good luck, {name}!')

# A dictionary for the simplified dragon text game
# The dictionary links a room to other rooms.

rooms = {
         'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'South': 'Bedroom',
         'text': 'You are in the Great Hall.'},
         'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar',
         'text': 'You are in the Bedroom.'},
         'Cellar': {'name': 'Cellar', 'West': 'Bedroom',
         'text': 'You are in the Cellar. Type "Exit" to end the game!'}
         }


directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
current_room = rooms['Great Hall']
exit = False

# game loop
while True:
    print(current_room['text'])
    command = input('\nEnter your move: ')
    if command == 'Exit':
        if current_room['name'] == 'Cellar':
            # The game completes when the user enters Cellar Room
            print('Congratulations !!')
            print("You've completed 'Dragon Text Game'.")
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        else:
            print(f'No door in {command} direction!')
         else:
        print('Invalid move!')
```

---

Output:

```
Dragon Text Game.
```

---

Move commands: South, North, East, West
Type "Exit" to end the game.
Let's start with your name:
Reb
Good luck, Reb!
You are in the Great Hall.

Enter your move: south
Invalid move!
You are in the Great Hall.

Enter your move: east
Invalid move!
You are in the Great Hall.

Enter your move: exit
Invalid move!
You are in the Great Hall.

Enter your move:

---

It keeps repeating. Created in PyCharm so all indents, white spaces, etc. are correct despite what you see above. This should be super simple. I just need to be able to exit at any time, call from dictionary, and move room to room. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: `south` is not `South`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `directions` to be

```py
directions = ['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'EAST', 'WEST']
```

And changing `if command in directions:` to `if command.upper() in directions:`

Your code currently does not work because it is case sensitive.  If you enter, `South` instead of `south` you will likely be able to move from room to room.  By forcing all inputs to be uppercase, you can avoid this issue.  Do something similar for checking `if command.upper() == 'EXIT'`

Comment: His code is case sensitive. Your suggested change makes it case insensitive. ;-)